# WF 4.x Receive activity - TrackingParticipant & how to obtain the content parameters

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am using WF 4.5 with a custom tracking system.
The tracking system will create task records in a custom database.
The tracking participant will create a task in the database whenever a Receive activity enters the 'Executing' state.
The tracking parcitipant will mark the task as completed in the database whenever a Receive activity enters the 'Closed' state.

When completing the task I need to fill in the user who executed the task.
The receive activity will have a custom class with a user property in it (content parameter).
I want to obtain this user property from the tracking participant.

How do I go about this?

```cs
public class WorkflowSystemTrackingParticipant : TrackingParticipant
{
     protected override void Track(TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout)
     {
           ActivityStateRecord aRecord = record as ActivityStateRecord;
           ... // get the parameters values send to the receive activity
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you track states and variables you want to track arguments also.

In your particular case you would track the `InArgument<string>` which holds the user you want.

```cs
new ActivityStateQuery
{
    Variables = { * },
    States = { "Executing", "Closed" },
    Arguments = { "UserArgument" }
}
```

Now you can get the *UserArgument* which is available on `ActivityStateRecord`:

```cs
protected override void Track(TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var aRecord = record as ActivityStateRecord;

    var userName = aRecord.Arguments["UserArgument"] as string;

    // do whatever you want with 'username'
}
```